# Magento 2: How to reset Per Page Record Show in Admin

Tags: magento2, admin, customer, page

I'm on **Magento Admin -> Customers -> All Customers**

I have 5K Customers. I have set 1000 per page to show record.

Now it's not loading & giving "Script Load" Error. I have checked on another browser it saved my 1000 set per page.

How to reset it?

I think Browser not able to handle.

Answer (score 3):

I have one dirty solution, before do this take a backup of `ui_bookmark` table.

Page limits are stored in `ui_bookmark` table, in that table change value `1000` to `whatever you want`

In `ui_bookmark` table

namespace -> `customer_listing`

identifier -> `current`

config -> change 1000 to whatever you want

I have tested it works. totally you need to change five places inside config values.

Comment: Can you post config value i seen it's very long. Can you please update in your answer where to replace exactly?

Comment: Just find `1000` use `ctrl+F` shortcut. I believe totally five founds only possible in inside config values. if not let me know I will update.